# Open application from shared social platform

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

If someone shares http://myappAdurl.com from facebook than if another one clicks link, if application exist on that device, my app should be open,
I added following line to my manifest but I could not get the result, not working.

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".TinyUrlTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tiny_url_test"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.myappAdurl.com"
                    android:path="/images"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="www.myappAdurl.com" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I also tried below project but it opens link such as com.commonsware.android.MY_ACTION
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler

Answer (score 0):

ok found that,
if i give

```
 android:pathPattern="/*.*"
```

inside data element, then it opens everything